# select function for new database in R

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to create a new data set using the `dplyr` package in R.

Let's say I have a data set called `olddata`, with several columns I wanted to extract to create a new data set:

```
olddata %>% select(year,number,total)
```

The result will show in the console, instead of modifying the dataset. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it like this:

```
 newdata<-olddata %>% select(year,number,total)
```

You can then view it like this:

```
((newdata<-olddata %>% select(year,number,total))
```

or simply type `newdata`